# Checking duplicates cross two columns in R

Tags: r, duplicates

For example, my data set is like this:

```
  Var1 Var2 value
1  ABC  BCD   0.5
2  DEF  CDE   0.3
3  CDE  DEF   0.3
4  BCD  ABC   0.5
```

`unique` and `duplicated` may not able to detect the duplication of row 3 and 4.

Since my data set is quite large so is there any efficient way to only keep the unique rows?
Like this:

```
  Var1 Var2 value
1  ABC  BCD   0.5
2  DEF  CDE   0.3
```

For your convince, you can use:

```
dat <- data.frame(Var1 = c("ABC", "DEF", "CDE", "BCD"),
                  Var2 = c("BCD", "CDE", "DEF", "ABC"),
                  value = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5))
```

Also, if possible is there any way to also produce a distribution table for the top 20 variables base on the Var1 (more than 10,000 levels).

P.S. I have tried `dat$count <- dat(as.character(dat$Var1))[as.character(dat$Var1)]`, but it just take too long to run.

Comment: So, if I understand correctly, there is no distinction between `Var1` and `Var2`?

Comment: @divibisan A very good question. Nope. ABC BCD is the same as BCD ABC.

Comment: Let us know if the link doesn't help. Re the "also if possible", better to ask one question at a time, I think.

Comment: @Frank thanks, I will try all of them. The biggest problem is time consuming.

Comment: Hm, if you want to make an example that can scale up to a large size (eg, as a function of some `n` rows, `ng` unique values), then we could reopen and get more focused answers on the performance/speed issue. Fwiw, I would use `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` and edit the columns so they're sorted ... `library(data.table); setDT(dat); dat[Var1 < Var2, c("Var1", "Var2") := .(Var2, Var1)]; unique(dat, by=c("Var1", "Var2"))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option would be to sort columns `Var1` and `Var2` rowwise and then apply `duplicated`.

```
idx <- !duplicated(t(apply(dat[c("Var1", "Var2")], 1, sort)))
dat[idx, ]
#  Var1 Var2 value
#1  ABC  BCD   0.5
#2  DEF  CDE   0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I would start with sorting the value1 and value2 first, and then use `unique`. When you have only two columns you can just use `pman`, and `pmin`:

```
dat <- data.frame(
   Var1 = c("ABC", "DEF", "CDE", "BCD"),
   Var2 = c("BCD", "CDE", "DEF", "ABC"),
   value = c(0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5))


library(dplyr)
dat %>% mutate(v1 = pmax(as.character(Var1), as.character(Var2)),
               v2 = pmin(as.character(Var1), as.character(Var2))) %>%
  select(v1, v2, value) %>% unique()

#   v1  v2 value
# 1 BCD ABC   0.5
# 2 DEF CDE   0.3
```

However it might be a bit more complicated when you have more columns `VarN`.