# Assign mean values and/or conditional assignment for unordered duplicate dyads

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I've come across something a bit above my skill set. I'm working with IMF trade data that consists of data between country dyads. The IMF dataset consists of ' unordered duplicate' records in that each country individually reports trade data. However, due to a variety of timing, recording systems, regime type, etc., there are discrepancies between corresponding values. I'm trying to manipulate this data in two ways:

1. Assign the mean values to the duplicated dyads.
2. Assign the dyad values conditionally based on a separate economic indicator or development index (who do I trust more?).

There are several discussions of identifying unordered duplicates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743130/removing-the-unordered-pairs-repeated-twice-in-a-file-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52613914/checking-duplicates-cross-two-columns-in-r), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487151/aggregate-a-data-frame-based-on-unordered-pairs-of-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1), and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/11193/how-do-i-remove-all-but-one-specific-duplicate-record-in-an-r-data-frame) but after a couple days of searching I have yet to see what I'm trying to do.

Here is an example of the raw data. In reality there are many more variables and several hundred thousand dyads:

```
reporter<-c('USA','GER','AFG','FRA','CHN')
partner<-c('AFG','CHN','USA','CAN','GER')
year<-c(2010,2010,2010,2009,2010)
import<-c(-1000,-2000,-2400,-1200,-2000)
export<-c(2500,2200,1200,2900,2100)
rep_econ1<-c(28,32,12,25,19)

imf<-data.table(reporter,partner,year,import,export,rep_econ1)

imf

   reporter partner year import export rep_econ1
1:      USA     AFG 2010  -1000   2500        28
2:      GER     CHN 2010  -2000   2200        32
3:      AFG     USA 2010  -2400   1200        12
4:      FRA     CAN 2009  -1200   2900        25
5:      CHN     GER 2010  -2000   2100        19
```

The additional wrinkle is that `import` and `export` are inverses of each other between the dyads, so they need to be matched and meaned with an absolute value.

For objective 1, the resulting `data.table` is:

**Mean**

```
 reporter   partner year    import  export  rep_econ1
  USA        AFG    2010    -1100   2450    28
  GER        CHN    2010    -2050   2100    32
  AFG        USA    2010    -2450   1100    12
  FRA        CAN    2009    -1200   2900    25
  CHN        GER    2010    -2100   2050    19
```

For objective 2:

**Conditionally Assign on Higher Economic Indicator (`rep_econ1`)**

```
 reporter   partner year    import  export  rep_econ1
 USA         AFG    2010    -1000   2500    28
 GER         CHN    2010    -2000   2200    32
 AFG         USA    2010    -2500   1000    12
 FRA         CAN    2009    -1200   2900    25
 CHN         GER    2010    -2200   2000    19
```

It's possible not all dyads are represented twice so I included a solo record. I prefer `data.table` but I'll go with anything that leads me down the right path.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pre - Processing:

```
library(data.table)

# get G = reporter/partner group and N = number of rows for each group
# Thanks @eddi for simplifying
imf[, G := .GRP, by = .(year, pmin(reporter, partner), pmax(reporter, partner))]
imf[, N := .N, G]
```

Option 1 (means)

```
# for groups with 2 rows, average imports and exports
imf[N == 2
    ,   `:=`(import = (import - rev(export))/2
           , export = (export - rev(import))/2)
    , by = G]

imf


#    reporter partner year import export rep_econ1 G N
# 1:      USA     AFG 2010  -1100   2450        28 1 2
# 2:      GER     CHN 2010  -2050   2100        32 2 2
# 3:      AFG     USA 2010  -2450   1100        12 1 2
# 4:      FRA     CAN 2009  -1200   2900        25 3 1
# 5:      CHN     GER 2010  -2100   2050        19 2 2
```

Option 2 (highest economic indicator)

```
# for groups with 2 rows, choose imports and exports based on highest rep_econ1
imf[N == 2
    , c('import', 'export') := {
        o <- order(-rep_econ1)
        import <- cbind(import, -export)[o[1], o]
        .(import, export = -rev(import))}
    , by = G]

imf


#    reporter partner year import export rep_econ1 G N
# 1:      USA     AFG 2010  -1000   2500        28 1 2
# 2:      GER     CHN 2010  -2000   2200        32 2 2
# 3:      AFG     USA 2010  -2500   1000        12 1 2
# 4:      FRA     CAN 2009  -1200   2900        25 3 1
# 5:      CHN     GER 2010  -2200   2000        19 2 2
```

Option 2 explanation: You need to select the row with the highest economic indicator (i.e. row `order(-rep_econ1)[1]`) and use that for `imports`, but if the second row is the "trusted" one, it needs to be reversed. Otherwise you'd have the countries switched, since the second reporter's imports (now the first element of `cbind(import, -export)[o[1],]`) would be assigned as the first reporter's imports (because it's the first element).

**Edit:**

If imports and exports are both positive in the input data and need to be positive in the output data, the two calculations above can be modified as

```
imf[N == 2
    ,   `:=`(import = (import + rev(export))/2
           , export = (export + rev(import))/2)
    , by = G]
```

And

```
imf[N == 2
    , c('import', 'export') := {
        o <- order(-rep_econ1)
        import <- cbind(import, export)[o[1], o]
        .(import, export = rev(import))}
    , by = G]
```

Comment: a standard trick to get the grouping is `by = .(pmin(reporter, partner), pmax(reporter, partner))`; + you can check .N on the fly without the need to precompute it

Comment: that's not what I meant about .N, I meant using an `if/else` (arguably more cumbersome) - you still need to precompute it if you want to select those rows only to begin with

Comment: Oh I see. I thought maybe I had missed a `data.table` update and `.N` could be used in `i` now

Comment: Thank you for you effort. I will try this out tomorrow. I appreciate the detailed response how it's actually carrying out the operation as opposed to simply code.

Comment: Country pairs need to account for the reporting year. The `pmin(reporter, partner)` lumps all dyad records into one group.  It doesn't look like you can just put year in the `pmin` statement?

Comment: You could put it in the `by` argument. Just add it to the front as `by = .(year, pmin(reporter, partner), pmax(reporter, partner))]`. I've edited the answer to add that.

Comment: Looks like `imf[, G := .GRP, by = .(pmin(reporter, partner), 
                        pmax(reporter, partner),year)]` works.

Comment: Sure, the order of variables in `by` doesn't matter

Comment: One last question (already marked as correct answer), I was mistaken and imports aren't recorded as negative. How would the code be adjusted to handle this; assuming it's a simple fix? I just flipped the signs before and after using your code so it's fine, but I was curious.

Comment: You may have already figured it out by now, but I added an edit for how the calculations change if imports and exports are both positive.